# Load objects in S3 bucket into Oracle on EC2

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket which gets objects in flat file format and i would like to read each object when it comes and load the data into a table on Oracle on EC2. Can someone please suggest any method to do it?

Comment: Just to confirm: do you want to load each object as they are uploaded into the bucket?

Comment: Not necessarily, i can wait and schedule them to load into DB in some time interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AWS Lambdas to be triggered as objects are uploaded into bucket s3 (s3:ObjectCreated:Put). So, in your lambda, you must configure a method to handle this event, in order to identify the `bucket` and `key`. From there, you can `get` the object and manipulate it to insert it into your Oracle database, for example.

You need to pay attention to the security group and VPC settings of lambda, to ensure that it will have access to EC2 instance that oracle is provisioned. I strongly recommend that you use [AWS SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/en/serverless/sam/) to provisioning your lambda. It greatly facilitates the deployment, development, and testing of your serverless function.

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html See this doc for more examples.

Comment: I dont want to move the object, rather leave it in the bucket after processing and inserting into DB. Would it be possible?

Comment: The file will stay in the bucket normally unless you specify a purge policy for files in the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a AWS Lambda function for s3:ObjectCreated event. Docs:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).